# Science Fiction and Fantasy Top User Swag

Tags: discussion, swag

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 1500 reputation (as of Feb 22) and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Science Fiction and Fantasy t-shirt in your size
- Science Fiction and Fantasy die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show/products/stack-exchange-sharpie)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: scifi.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: scifi.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show/products/stack-exchange-sharpie), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store as soon as we're able)</sub>

Comment: Ooooooh, shiny.

Comment: I worship Sharpie markers! What a nice thing for you to do :)

Comment: I love this site!

Comment: This is wonderful!

Comment: Cool!  Thanks!  (Since I seem to be the top question asker, do I get a green jumpsuit with question marks all over it so I can jump in front of people and say, "Riddle me this!" ?)

Comment: @TangoOversway: thanks, Tango, now I need [brain bleach](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8081/are-there-any-jedi-or-sith-droids/8082#8082)...

Comment: @Wikis: Are you implying that I look anything less than stunning in a green jumpsuit?

Comment: I have never been so excited to come in second-to-last place (I need to get working)!

Comment: I love swag!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, you guys are just awesome!

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Wow! This is great. I love scifi.se :)

Comment: This is awesome...I am the last person on page 2. If I get bumped off does that mean no care package?

Comment: Just submitted my info and waiting for all the swag I will be getting. Thanks guys

Comment: @spencer the snap shot of the top 2 page users is as of Feb 22nd when Rebecca made this post. Any new comers to page 2 after that will not be getting the email.

Comment: The links to the sharpies in the store seem to be broken.

Comment: I, er, what?  I had no clue I was that high up on the list!

Comment: Ack, I was flipping back and forth between tabs (apparently a Small in the brand I usually buy is a Large in his brand), and may have submitted the wrong tshirt size - is there any way to check/confirm?

Comment: @Izkata you submitted Large.

Comment: @Jin Phwew, thanks  =^_^=

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!

Comment: I knew I was answering SciFi questions instead of doing work for a reason! Thanks, SE!

Comment: @Jin I see you did the design? I was searching around and couldn't find what the logo is referencing, or is it altogether new logo? I am talking about the circle with three moons and the alien skulls.

Comment: @spencer that logo appears on the site header right now(to the right with the girl). I also use it for site's Apple touch logo. A simplified version of it is used for favicon.

Comment: @Jin Yes I saw those. I meant is the symbol referencing some literature or movie? Thanks.

Comment: @spencer I see! The logo was inspired by rune circles, with some scifi elements.(3 eyed alien skull, biohazard-ish moon crescents). The rune letters spell out "Forty Two." You can read more about the design process [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/981/44).

Comment: Sweet! This is the second site I qualified for.

Comment: My second site, too!  First one for me was [security.se].  Thanks @RebeccaChernoff & SEI!

Comment: To quote the immortal Maxwell Smart: "Missed it by THAT much..."

Comment: @Iszi [Cooking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/)--of all things--for me. And now [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) too, which makes sense.

Comment: @MajorStackings Wow.  That takes me back.

Comment: How do I know if I should be receiving this package? I'vbe not been keeping a close check on my Rep...

Comment: @Rebecca - is there any ETA one when it is supposed to be shipped?

Comment: Has anyone received this package yet? I have not received mine.

Comment: @Rebecca or anyone - has the swag already been posted?

Comment: @BennyMcBenBen I haven't, I don't think anyone has.

Comment: @Wikis Swag tends to take 6 to 8 weeks, I think you still need to be patient.

Comment: @Pureferret You should have received an e-mail with a link to a form you'll need to fill out, if you qualified for the swag.

Comment: @Iszi I know I had enough rep. How do I know what page I was on from then? I've not received an email *to my knowledge*.

Comment: Did anybody get theirs yet, or is it too soon?

Comment: @MPelletier Nope, nothing here.

Comment: I did not get my either... so sad :(

Comment: Were we supposed to get a confirmation when submitting the form? I remember wondering why I never got an email or anything after submitting?

Comment: I got my swag today. It was worth the wait. Thanks!

Comment: Swag now invading Canada...

Answer (score 8):

Woke up this morning to the mail person giving me my package!

[image: original image]
(sorry I'm still half asleep...)

[image: swag box contents]

Comment: Mine came, too. Yeah!

Comment: Mine arrived today.  Finally, I can cover my upper body!

Comment: Mine showed up last night, too. Sometimes a multiple-month lead time has a benefit: I had completely forgotten about it, so its arrival was a total surprise.

Comment: Wonderful surprise at the office this morning when I was handed a forgotten package :) Thanks for the swag

Answer (score 2):

Rebecca, has the swag been sent out?  People are wondering what's up.

Comment: Just to clear things out, the swag was totally unexpected and is absolutely sweet. I don't think anyone's demanding it or feeling entitled. I know I'm not. I was just wondering if my *Canadian-ness* had ruled me out. Or my being not so active in the past few months... :(

Comment: The swag has been mailed and should be arriving in a few days, though of course longer if you're somewhere shipping just takes longer and all that jazz... (:

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Thanks for the update!

Comment: Awesome, so we should be getting in in 1-2 weeks?

Comment: @Teknophilia - it's a StackExchange site. So it will be [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/119280)

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: yep, got mine today. Thanks Rebecca!

Answer (score 0):

Curses! I hadn't updated my email address! Noooo!