# Will there be any more "swag packs"?

Tags: discussion, swag

A few of the older users have mentioned some [site swag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1544/science-fiction-and-fantasy-top-user-swag) that was sent out to high-rep users a couple of years ago (including pens, stickers, t-shirts, etc) to reward their participation.

Not that anyone could accuse me of being mercenary (perish the thought), but will this generosity be repeated anytime soon?

Failing that, will the [SE: Shop](http://shop.stackexchange.com/) that was linked be opening again?

[image: SFF Sticker]

Comment: I was going to title this one "gimme, gimme, gimme!" but I thought that might be a bit too obvious

Comment: Based on Anna's response to [Has Stack Exchange discontinues the tactics of contests?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3009/5184), they're willing to back us up if we come up with a good idea.

Comment: @phantom42 - Is "gimme, gimme, gimme" not a sufficiently good plan then?

Comment: @phantom42 - the only time someone proposed a contest on meta (me), they didn't even back it up morally/spiritually, never mind with prizes. Simplly ignored. However, contests with prizes **differ** from high-rep SWAG rewards (which I can attest does happen at certain points, though I will leave to community team to disclose specifics should they choose to)

Comment: I thought that was cause we was speshul!  We would might not be speshul if other hoomans got them after we did.

Comment: @Tango - I still think you're special (school)...

Comment: Thank you, @Richard.  I feel better now.